# Symfony enable to find and delete item

Tags: symfony-3.4

First, this is my code :

```
   /**
     *
     * @Route("/delete", name="team_delete_v4")
     */
    public function deleteTeam(Request $request, BaseEquipe $team, $id)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(BaseEquipe::class);
        $equipe = $repository->find($team->getId());
        $entityManager->remove($equipe);


        return $this->redirectToRoute('equipe_index_v4');
    }
```

I've a function in my controller where I try to get/find an object by his ID and delete this object. For some reason Symfony is telling me **"Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "team"."** and I can't guess how to resolve it. Please could you help me guys ?

PS : My version is actually 3.4

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you get 3 parameters, the $request, the $team and an id, but how symfony know witch $team are you sending to your controller. You have to pass the id in the url:

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/delete/{id}", name="team_delete_v4")
     */
    public function deleteTeam(Request $request, BaseEquipe $team)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->remove($team);


        return $this->redirectToRoute('equipe_index_v4');
    }
```

Note that the url now is */delete/{id}*, when you declare an id in a controller, symfony will find the object with this id. [Take a look at the docs.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#automatically-fetching-objects-paramconverter)

So in your template, you have to pass the id of the object that you want to delete:

```
path("team_delete_v4", {id: team.id})
```

Sorry for my english, hope this help.